# Como validar en paralelo varias conexiones a diversos Directorios Activos y terminar cuando alguno responda en c#

Tags: c#, directorioactivo

Tengo un requerimiento para autenticarme contra varios Directorios Activos. La idea mandar en paralelo varias peticiones a los diferentes Directorios Activos configurados y esperar la respuesta positiva de alguno. Actualmente se tiene

```
    public Task<ItemDirectorioActivo> AutenticarDirectorioActivo(List<DatosConexion> conexiones)
{
    foreach (var conexion in conexiones)
    {
        try
        {
            CamposDirectorioActivo = Enum.GetNames(typeof(CamposLdap)).ToArray().Select(x => x).ToArray();
            AdministracionDirectorioActivo Ldap = new AdministracionDirectorioActivo(conexion);
            string distinguishedName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(conexion.DN) ? Ldap.ObtenerBaseDn() : conexion.DN;
            SearchResultEntry resultadoBusqueda = Ldap.ObtenerObjeto(conexion.NombreUsuario, distinguishedName, CamposDirectorioActivo);
            if (resultadoBusqueda != null)
                return Task.Run(() => Mapeo(resultadoBusqueda));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteMessage(LevelLog.Error, $"Server: {conexion.Servidor}");
            Log.WriteException(LevelLog.Error, ex);
        }
    }

    return Task.Run(() => new ItemDirectorioActivo());

}
```

Como podría ejecutar el proceso de todas las conexiones en paralelo. Gracias

Comment: Me parece que [ya habías preguntado esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/424935/155807)

Comment: Por favor, no repitas las preguntas.. en su lugar, edita la pregunta original, donde ya te habian hecho comentarios...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método [`WhenAny`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-5.0) de la clase `Task`.
A grandes rasgos, `WhenAny` acepta una colección de `Task` y devuelve una `Task` que se resolverá cuando lo haga la primera `Task` de la colección.

Voy a simplificar tu escenario por el bien del ejemplo. Supongamos

```
public Task<T> Method(IEnumerable<ConnectionData> connections)
{
    // ...
}

private Task<Connection> CreateConnection(ConnectionData data) { ... }
```

El método `CreateConnection` va a establecer la conexión de forma asíncrona con el DA dados unos datos de conexión.

Vamos a crear una `Task` por cada dato de conexión (argumento `connections`) que va a trabajar en paralelo, cada `Task` va a resolverse en una conexión.
Una vez tengamos la colección de `Task`, podemos llamar al método `WhenAny` y esperar a que complete una `Task` (la primera).
Con la primera `Task` resultado de la invocación del método `WhenAny`, podemos obtener el valor.

```
public async Task<T> Method(IEnumerable<ConnectionData> connections)
{
    var tasks = connections.Select(CreateConnection);
    var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

    var connection = await task;
    // ...
}

private Task<Connection> CreateConnection(ConnectionData data) { ... }
```

Con la `Task` "ganadora", podemos sacar el valor con `var connection = await task;` sin forzar la `Task` a hacer el trabajo de nuevo, ya que el resultado está encapsulado en la `Task` sin importar cuántas veces se "*awaitee*".

---

El **problema** de esta implementación es que estarás creando múltiples conexiones pese a sólo necesitar una. Por ello, cuando obtenemos la primera conexión, las otras deberían cancelarse.
Para ello podemos usar un `CancellationToken` compartido.

```
public async Task<T> Method(IEnumerable<ConnectionData> connections)
{
    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var tasks = connections.Select(data => CreateConnection(data, cancellation.Token));
    var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    // Cancelamos aquellas Task que no han acabado
    cancellation.Cancel();
    var connection = await task;
    // ...
}

private Task<Connection> CreateConnection(ConnectionData data, CancellationToken token) { ... }
```

Deberás propagar el `token` hasta el método donde se crea la conexión (que, me figuro que tendrá una sobrecarga para admitirlo).

---

Por último, y un poco *offtopic*, deberías evitar los *statements* del tipo

```
return Task.Run(() => new ItemDirectorioActivo());
```

Cuando se invoca `Task.Run` se está poniendo en cola el trabajo y consume recursos del *ThreadPool*. En caso de que quieras devolver un valor envuelto en una `Task`, mejor usa

```
return Task.FromResult(new ItemDirectorioActivo());
```

Es mucho más óptimo en tiempo y recursos de la máquina.

Espero que sirva.